# Create a sub array from an array in PHP

Tags: php

Need help

Below is the requirement details

```
//Input Array
$folders = array('x','y','z',4,'s');

//Output array will be like this
$u = array(
    'x'=>array(
        y'=>array(
            'z'=>array(
                4=>'s'
            )
        )
     )
);
```

generic function for above requirement ( Max array length  : n)

Comment: Please post the code you tried and tell what's wrong with the expected result.

Comment: Use array_map() function

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `array_walk` along with `array_reverse` as

```
array_walk(array_reverse($folders),function($v,$k)use(&$folders){
    $folders = $k ? [$v => $folders] : $v;
});
```

Or

```
function nest_array($array){
    if(count($array) < 2)
        return $array;
    $key = array_shift($array);
    return array($key => nest_array($array));
}

print_r(nest_array($folders));
```

Comment: Using `array_reverse($folders)` as an argument to `array_walk()` raises an `E_STRICT` error, but otherwise this seems pretty neat!

Comment: haha I literally just posted a pretty much identical answer to your edit. Recursion ftw :)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply do reverse loop, like:-

```
$newArray = null;
$ar = array('x','y','z',4,'s');
$arLen = count($ar)-1;

for($i=$arLen; $i >= 0; $i--){
  $newArray = is_null($newArray) ? $ar[$i] : [$ar[$i] => $newArray];
}
```

Working Example: https://eval.in/414821

Answer (score 0):

I quite like @Narendra's answer, but I figured I'd post a recursive solution as another option:

```php
function recurse(&$tail)
{
    $head = array_shift($tail);
    return $tail ? [$head => recurse($tail)] : $head;
}

$folders = array('x','y','z',4,'s');
$u = recurse($folders);

print_r($u);
```

This version keeps popping off the first element (`$head`) of the array and recursing on the remaining elements (`$tail`) until there are no elements left (in which case `array_shift()` returns `null`.

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [x] => Array
        (
            [y] => Array
                (
                    [z] => Array
                        (
                            [4] => s
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Hope this helps :)